# How do I let go the ownership of the mind?

Tags: anatman, mind, thoughtprocess, guidance, patience

If someone offense me on physical things like "*You are not beautiful, You are poor, You are not smart*", I can bear it. Actually I don't care much.

But, If someone offense me on my thoughts like "*You are not kind, You are greedy*", It's hard to bear. Sometimes, I got aversion.

How can I overcome this ?

I asked a related question here.

- [How Am I not the owner of the mind?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/37202/17744)

Comment: What's the difference between "you're not kind, you're greedy", and "the mind reacted from non-kindness and greed as its condition"? Can you see any difference in both perspectives? Maybe if you analyze and investigate between these two kinds of views, you might be able to find something useful for you dilemma. Kind regards!

Comment: Keep establishing perception of non-self. When 'i am' doesn't occur, then 'i am good/bad' doesn't occur. It occurs due to frequent giving of inappropriate attention. If it wasn't occuring you would not make an evaluation 'another said this about me and it is a cause for sadness' or 'i am bad because of this, as in i prefer he didn't say these disagreeable things'. You would know that this is just some ignorant speech of ignorant people and feel compassion for their predicament.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to subtle Upadana. (clinging)
There are three kinds of clinging.
-Kama Upadana (it seems you have less of this)
-Dithi upadana
-Atta upadana. (perhaps this is your problem)
-Silabbatha Upadana

upādāna:
Clinging; attachment; sustenance for becoming and birth — attachment to sensuality, to views, to precepts and practices, and to theories of the self.

The way to eliminate Upadana is to follow the Noble Eightfold Path. It is a gradual training of Sila (virtues), Samadhi (concentration) and Panna (wisdom).

Comment: There are four types of clinging; clinging to sensuality, clinging to rites and observances, clinging to views and clinging to the doctrine of a self.

Answer (score 0):

Just develop clarity around this question. Just this analysis displaces the activity responsible for this and any other view concerning the ownership of the mind. It's that simple.