# Can we ignore sense doors through meditation?

Tags: meditation, practice, six-senses

In the process of reading a book, we need only the mind and the eyes. There is no need of ears and tongue.

In the process of hearing *Dhamma*,there may no need of eyes.

Are there any meditation practice to ignore senses completely for a period of time ?

(I'm looking for a specific meditation practice designed to achieve this, I know that we can achieve a similar result by doing Ānāpāna/breathing exercises,but may take much time )

Comment: Short answer to your question is no, but if you could clarify the reason why you're asking, perhaps there might be another answer. Also, please bear in mind that a lot of the insights provided in buddhism primarily builds on direct experiences from sustained practice, not by intellectual sports like asking/discussing.

Comment: @Erik looking for a way to get rid of distractions, a way to stop breaking progression. Thanks :)

Comment: @Dum I updated the answer with links to more details I have covered else where.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot avoid contact (described below) hence one cannot ignore the sense doors totally:

[image]

[Cha Chakka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/26.6-Chachakka-S-m148-piya.pdf)

[image]

[(Samuday’atthaṅgama) Loka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/7.5-Samudayatthangama-Loka-S-s12.44-piya.pdf)

What one can do it to ensure any contact (described above) does not result in craving and break the above progression of events at `feeling`. This can be achieved through meditation.

See

- [Food and other cravings, and guarding the senses](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/37262/295)
- [Rejecting clinging to both pleasure and displeasure](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/37166/295)
- [How should I watch sensations in Vipassana meditation?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/36912/295)
- [Sankhara meditation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/34073/295)
- [Meditation technique to reduce/control pain/sorrow/loss](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/21545/295)

answers for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much sir :)